# libart.so art::gc::Heap::WaitForGcToCompleteLocked(art::gc::GcCause, art::Thread*)

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-room, android-adapter, android-cursorloader

Title Issue:
The primary problem lies in the title.

Second Issue:
There is an issue related to [libart.so] art::gc::Heap::WaitForGcToCompleteLocked.

Context:
I am utilizing an adapter with a cursor loader, and during scrolling, I fetch data from the database using Room and runBlocking. I am uncertain why this error is occurring. Can anyone identify how to resolve these issues? I have received emails from Play Store Android Vitals regarding these concerns.